# Differences in pbkdf2 between php and node.js

Tags: php, node.js, cryptography, pbkdf2

I'm using Node.js to generate a password hashing using pbkdf2 and store them into the db. Also I'm making some web pages made with php that let you user reset their password, so unless I use a web service in node.js to build the hash, I would like to have the algorithm working in the 2 systems. Unfortunately seems that I get different results and I'm not able to mix the two libraries. The code I'm using in node.js uses the module password-hash-and-salt that basically calls crypto.pbkdf2 , while php uses hash_pbkdf2.

Those are the scripts I'm using to test it:

PHP:

```
<?php
$password = $argv[1];
$iterations = 10000;
$length = 64;

$salt = mcrypt_create_iv($length, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
$key = hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $password, $salt, $iterations, $length,true);
echo "HASH: pbkdf2\\$" . $iterations . "\\$" . bin2hex($key) . "\\$" . bin2hex($salt). "\n";

echo "Key length: " . strlen(bin2hex($key)) . "\n";
echo "Hash length: " . strlen(bin2hex($salt)) . "\n";

?>
```

NODE.JS:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var request = require('request');
var hasher = require('password-hash-and-salt');

if (process.argv[2] == 'generate') {
    var password = process.argv[3];
    console.log("Generating hash for password " + password);
    hasher(password).hash(function(err, hash) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Result: " + hash);
        }
    });
} else {
    var password = process.argv[3];
    var hash = process.argv[4];
    console.log("Testing " + password + " against " + hash);
    hasher(password).verifyAgainst(hash, function(error, verified) {
        if (error) console.log(error);
        else {
            console.log("Verification result: " + verified);
        }
    });
}
```

NODE.JS LIB PART:

```
var calcHash = function() {
                crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, 64, function(err, key) {
                    if(err)
                        return callback(err);
                    var res = 'pbkdf2$' + iterations + 
                                '$' + key.toString('hex') + 
                                '$' + salt.toString('hex');
                    callback(null, res);
                })      
            };

            if(!salt) {
                crypto.randomBytes(64, function(err, gensalt) {
                    if(err)
                        return callback(err);
                    salt = gensalt;
                    calcHash();
                });     
            } else {
                calcHash();
            }
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or that the algorithms are incompatible ?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try my PBKDF2 test vectors at https://github.com/Anti-weakpasswords/PBKDF2-Test-Vectors  in order to see if the same values in both give the same output (or even tell which function they're using, since I have results for a variety of HMACs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NodeJS PBKDF2 defaults to SHA-1, which should explain the differences.

I would strongly urge you to directly use the NodeJS PBKDF2 functions. Your JS wrapper (which you don't link to) uses it as well, it's little more than a small wrapper lib.

Comment: I've updated the question with the relevant js part. I'll check if it works with sha-1

Comment: you were right, after changing php code to use sha-1 everything is working fine. Thanks a lot !